# GJK Algorithm triangle face tests

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, vector, collision-detection

I am rebuilding my GJK algorithm but I'm having issues with triangular face tests for my tetrahedron. My point and edge tests are complete however.

I want to test if the origin is outside of the tetrahedron and closest to a particular triangular face.

So far my method was to calculate the normals of a triangular face and do a series of dot product tests to determine whether or not the origin is outside and closest to that face. My method has one main issue: I cannot guarantee my normals are facing outwards. See this figure I made for a better description:

[image]

As you can see the same triangle, depending on the ordering of the vertices requires different cross product 'ordering' to produce normals that face outwards. Is there any way for me to ensure they face outwards? If not, is there a better method for testing these faces? Here's an example of my process:

```
if (dot(ABC, AO) > 0) {
        if (dot(ACD, AO) <= 0) {
            if (dot(ADB, AO) <= 0) {
                if (dot(DCB, DO) <= 0) {
                    // closest to face of ABC

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:

> ABC, ACD, ADB, DCB = triangular face normals (as you can see I'm assuming the 'left' triangle from the picture)
>
> AO = vector from A to origin
>
> DO =  vector from A to origin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's work with face ABC. Form a normal using `N = cross(B-A, C-A)`. If `dot(N, D-A) > 0`, then `N` is inward pointing and needs to be reversed. Finally, normalize `N` to get a unit normal if needed.

Comment: awesome thanks, i think my face test code is wrong... any chance you know off the top of your head a good way to determine if its contained in the area covered by 'elongating' the triangle face outwards along its normal, creating a prisms shape protruding out the side. My code above doesnt work if two adjacent faces are nearly parallel

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. I thought the problem was determining if the origin was contained in the tetrahedron. (By the way, the easiest test for that, I think, is to use the [barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system_(mathematics)) of the origin with respect to the vertices.)

Comment: i am trying to determine if the origin is contained, but if it isnt want to know which face its outside of.

Comment: It's not clear what "which face it's outside of" means in all cases. For instance, how would you classify a point that's directly above vertex A (with respect to the normal to face BCD)?

Comment: You can easily find the distance from the test point to the four lines normal to the faces and passing through the face centroids (e.g., (A + B + C) / 3 for face ABC). Perhaps that, together with knowledge of which side of each face the point is on, gets you what you need to classify the point.

Comment: My apologies, i've broken down region outside of the tetra hedron, i refer to them as the origin being closest to an point, as you stated above, an edge, or a face. heres an image of it in 2d, http://i.imgur.com/AmYNO.png , you can think of the face areas as the area of thata triangle protruding forward. Heres an awful attempt by me drawing it in 3d, http://i.imgur.com/hNjy3.png , green being closest to a face, and red being closest to an edge

Comment: You can test whether a point is in the extrusion of a face as follows. First test whether the point is "above" the face by checking that `dot(face normal, point - a face vertex) > 0`. Then project the point into the plane of the face and testing whether the projection is in the face triangle. See [here](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html) for ways to solve the triangle containment problem.